# Instance initialization taking a hash

Tags: ruby

Most of the online material has initialization like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessors :a, :b, :c
  def initialize(a,b,c)
    @a = a
    @b = b
    @c = c
  end
end
```

with or without defaults. Creating a new instance is:

```
n = MyClass.new(1,2,3)
n.a # => 1
n.b # => 2
n.c # => 3
```

I would like to know how to initialize the instance with hash syntax, like:

```
n = MyClass.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3)
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
n = MyClass.new(:b => 2, :a => 1, :c => 3)
```

Is this difficult to implement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ruby keyword arguments, available in Ruby 2.0 and above

Format in initializer arguments is `variable:`

```
class MyClass
    attr_accessors :a, :b, :c
    def initialize(a:, b:, c: )
      @a = a
      @b = b
      @c = c
    end
  end
```

Comment: You might have thought that this was obvious, but I wasn't able to get this syntax to work without putting in defaults (i.e.: `def initialize(a: nil, b: 4, c: foo)`.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: So let me know if this isn't on base.  When you add the named arguments they are requirements and you have to pass all of them in.  If you don't pass them in the the initialize of the new class will fail.

Comment: The way I have it listed in the comment, I do not. Omitted parameters are initialized with the default.  The way you have it listed above the IDE complained about unexpected commas and the application would throw a cryptic exception. It wants something after the `:` and before the `,`.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the commas go after the :

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the following?

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :hash
  def initialize(hash)
    @hash = hash
  end
end

e1 = MyClass.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3)
  #=> #<MyClass:0x007f88240d66b0 @hash={:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}>
e1.hash
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}

e2 = MyClass.new( { :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3 } )
  #=> #<MyClass:0x007f882281d678 @hash={:c=>3, :b=>2, :a=>1}> 
e2.hash
  #=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}

e3 = MyClass.new(:b => 2, :a => 1, :c => 3)
  #=> #<MyClass:0x007f88240bd408 @hash={:b=>2, :a=>1, :c=>3}> 
e3.hash
  #=> {:b=>2, :a=>1, :c=>3}
```

Are `e1`, `e2` and `e3` "equivalent"?

```
e1 == e2
  #=> false 
e1 == e3
  #=> false 

e1.hash == e2.hash
  #=> true 
e1.hash == e3.hash
  #=> true
```

Another way of looking at this is as follows:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :args
  def initialize(*args)
    @args = args
  end
end

e1 = MyClass.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3)
  #=> #<MyClass:0x007f88240d66b0 @hash={:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}>
e1.args
  #=> [{:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}]
```

which shows that only a single argument (a hash) is being passed to `new`.

Answer (score 0):

It can be as simple as:

```
require 'ostruct'

class MyClass < OpenStruct
end

n = MyClass.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3)

n.a
# => 1
```